Error in mvtnorm package installation in R on Linux (CentOS)
Can anyone tell me why I am having the following error when I am trying to install the mvtnorm package in R from my HPC terminal that is Linux (CentOS) based?
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mvtnorm'
* removing '/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/R/library/mvtnorm

I have pasted the full error below in case anyone wants to have a look.
> install.packages("mvtnorm")
trying URL 'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/src/contrib/mvtnorm_1.2-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 663517 bytes (647 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 647 KB

* installing *source* package 'mvtnorm' ...
** package 'mvtnorm' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -I"/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/include -I/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/lib -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/build/80754af9/r-base_1589917437985/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c C_FORTRAN_interface.c -o C_FORTRAN_interface.o
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -I"/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/include -I/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/lib -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/build/80754af9/r-base_1589917437985/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c lpmvnorm.c -o lpmvnorm.o
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -I"/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/include -I/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/lib -fvisibility=hidden -fpic  -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/build/80754af9/r-base_1589917437985/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c ltMatrices.c -o ltMatrices.o
ltMatrices.c: In function 'R_ltMatrices_solve':
ltMatrices.c:139:57: error: expected ')' before 'FCONE'
             F77_CALL(dtptri)(&lo, &di, &iJ, dans, &info FCONE FCONE);
                                                         ^~~~~
ltMatrices.c:144:67: error: expected ')' before 'FCONE'
             F77_CALL(dtpsv)(&lo, &tr, &di, &iJ, dans, dansx, &ONE FCONE FCONE FCONE);
                                                                   ^~~~~
ltMatrices.c: In function 'R_syMatrices_chol':
ltMatrices.c:375:48: error: expected ')' before 'FCONE'
         F77_CALL(dpptrf)(&lo, &iJ, dans, &info FCONE);
                                                ^~~~~
ltMatrices.c: In function 'R_vectrick':
ltMatrices.c:464:35: error: expected ')' before 'FCONE'
                         dans, &iJ FCONE FCONE FCONE FCONE);
                                   ^~~~~
ltMatrices.c:475:35: error: expected ')' before 'FCONE'
                         dans, &iJ FCONE FCONE FCONE FCONE);
                                   ^~~~~
make: *** [/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: ltMatrices.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'mvtnorm'
* removing '/mnt/beegfs/home/apiya2021/.conda/envs/test_env/lib/R/library/mvtnorm'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmpcxjtcG/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("mvtnorm") :
  installation of package 'mvtnorm' had non-zero exit status


I am running the command in the R session in a miniconda environment on hpc cause I will need to run some python libraries as well later. Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue with mvtnorm here?

Looks like an issue with how the Fortran compiler flags are set up within the conda environment. Already tried switching to another R conda?
